# Sorting list based on date and amt.Getting null pointer exception when two dates are null in comparison

Tags: java

```
Collections.sort(foos, new Comparator<Foo>){
public int compare(Foo a, Foo b){
  int dateComparison=a.date.before(b.date);      
   return dateComparison == 0 ?a.amt.compareTo(b.amt) : dateComparison;
    }    
});
```

Comment: So if two dates are `null` what does that mean for your sort?  Just sort by the amount?

Comment: Conditionon is if two dates are equal then sort on amount.date can contain null value but amt will never at any case.Whn I used the above code I get null pointer exception when it first compare two dates which are null in before() methods

Comment: Well, obviously.  But are two `null` dates equal?

Comment: Yes two null dates are considered equal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

> two null dates are considered equal

So, you simply need to add in a check for two `null` dates...

```
Collections.sort(foo, new Comparator<Foo>() {
    public int compare(Foo a, Foo b) {

        int dateComparison = 0;
        if (a.date == null && b.date == null) {
            dateComparison = 0;
        } else if (a.date == null) {
            dateComparison = -1;
        } else if (b.date == null) {
            dateComparison = 1;
        }

        return dateComparison == 0 ? a.amt.compareTo(b.amt) : dateComparison;
    }
});
```

Now, you will need to adjust the `dateComparison` for when one of the `date` values is `null` based on your needs, but, that's the basic idea

Comment: thanks@madProgrammer :how can achieve this : if date contain null in an object then that object should not be considered  in sorting

Comment: @MASHUKAHMED Well, either it needs to be removed from the list or possible sorted to the bottom of the list, you can't "partially" sort a list, it doesn't make sense